# why component generated by ng cli has the spec file with 2 beforeeach method?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

When I run `ng c my-component`, I get a spec file that has 2 beforeEach methods.

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyComponent ]
   })
   .compileComponents();
 }));

  beforeEach(() => {
   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
   component = fixture.componentInstance;
   fixture.detectChanges();
 });

 it('should create', () => {
   expect(component).toBeTruthy();
 });
});
```

Why do I have 2 `beforeEach`, do I need both of them? All the tutorial are showing only the second, i.e. *the non-asynchronous* one. Also code needed to run a basic test is split among those 2 methods. Any reason?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 8):

As **compileComponents()** is an async function returning a promise the beforeEach is marked with *async*. So Jasmine knows that everything has to be resolved before moving to the next step (-> here the second beforeEach).
The second beforeEach includes synchronous code only so it's not marked with *async*.

If you put everything in one beforeEach it could happen that **compileComponents()** is not resolved until **createComponent(MyComponent)** is called - this **could** lead to errors but if **compileComponents()** is fast enough it won't.

Comment: Wouldn't simply awaiting the first portion and then continuing to the second portion in a single beforeeach still work? (spoiler, it always has for me) This seems much more clear than having two separate.

Answer (score 1):

The spec file is a test suite file. Essentially one of the `beforeEach`es  sets up your test bed and the other creates an instance of your component for testing. You do need them both in order to write your tests and for the tests to actually work. The only test you are running is the `it` block. So essentially it is up to you how to define your test env.

Comment: one is `async` and the other one is not. Is there any reason for that? For instance, I've commented out the `async` version, transferred all the code to the `non-async` version, and my test is still working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation now documents the "Consolidated setup" in a single `beforeEach()`: https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#consolidated-setup

And there is a PR that would make this the new behavior of angular/cli: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/22862